# How to load the multiple js files in single javascript file, without using document.write?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype) {
    if (filetype == "js") {
        var fileref = document.createElement('script');
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
        //fileref.async = false;
    }
    else if (filetype == "css") { //if filename is an external CSS file
        var fileref = document.createElement("link");
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", filename);
        //fileref.async = false;
    }
    if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
        console.log("check file", head.appendChild(fileref));
        fileref.sync = true;
    head.appendChild(fileref);
}
```

i am using above function, but i am getting few error, I think files are not loaded one by one.
I want to load one by one js file.
How to load multiple scripts files one by one.

```
loadjscssfile ("js/scripts/jquery.js", "js");    
loadjscssfile ("js/scripts/angular.min.js", "js");   
loadjscssfile ("js/scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js", "js");   
loadjscssfile ("js/scripts/angular-resource.min.js", "js");    
loadjscssfile "js/scripts/angular-route.min.js", "js");       
loadjscssfile ("js/scripts/moment.min.js", "js");    
loadjscssfile("js/scripts/humanize-duration.js", "js");    
loadjscssfile("js/scripts/angular-timer.min.js", "js");     
loadjscssfile("js/scripts/angular-translate.min.js", "js");    
loadjscssfile("js/scripts/angular-translate-loader-url.min.js", "js");
```

Comment: But ...... why? What's wrong with HTML

Comment: Nothing wrong, but i want to implement my code without document.write();

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). You can load js files on demand.

Here is an example http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can look a task runner like [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) to automatically inject JS files and/or CSS files into your HTML ?

For Grunt use the [fileblocks plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-file-blocks) and for gulp, the [inject plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject)

Comment: Yes , is there any reference for this?

Answer (score 1):

[Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) can help you. It can make one .js file from many
But be careful - use obfuscation for .min.js files can make you many problems, dont use it when you will make one(or two) big .js files